# Laravel 9 prevent saving both models if one create() fails

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel application, I have two models that I'm saving, first, an `Application` and then a modelable class model, however, if one of them fails to save for whatever reason then I want to prevent saving both as they both rely on one another.

I've tried wrapping everything in a `try/catch`, the `Application` model saves, but when my `modelable` fails it's not prevent the `Application` from saving.

What am I missing?

My code is:

```php
try {

    // generate metadata about application
    $threadUUID = (string) Str::uuid();
    $submittedAt = Carbon::now();

    // create application instance
    $application = Application::create([
        'user_id' => $affiliate->user_id,
        'company_id' => $affiliate->company_id,
        'country_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->country->id,
        'product_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->product->id,
        'serve_method_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->serve_method->id,
        'application_form_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->application_form->id,
        'pingtree_group_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->pingtree_group->id,
        'affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id,
        'thread_uuid' => $threadUUID,
        'status' => 'pending',
        'submitted_at' => $submittedAt
    ]);

    // init a new provider class instance
    $provider = new $providerClass($request, $application, $affiliate);

    // create modelable data
    $modelable = $modelableClass::create(array_merge($provider->getMappedApplication(), [
        'user_id' => $application->user_id,
        'company_id' => $affiliate->company_id,
        'country_id' => $application->country_id,
        'product_id' => $application->product_id,
        'serve_method_id' => $application->serve_method_id,
        'application_form_id' => $application->application_form_id,
        'pingtree_group_id' => $application->pingtree_group_id,
        'affiliate_id' => $application->affiliate_id,
    ]));

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
        'legacy_response' => [
            'Result' => 'Invalid',
            'Message' => 'Error saving application',
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Look up how to do these inside a transaction.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#database-transactions